# Why is multi threaded operation on one vector slow?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, hash

I have a lot of keys (c-strings) and I want to precalculate their hashes. I made a struct that holds the key data and its hash. I pushed those structs into vector and divided the vector into groups. Each group of keys will be hashed by one thread.

Minimal example:

```
struct Key
{
    char* data;    // mostly 10 character strings
    uint64_t hash; // init with 0 and compute later
};

// hash group of keys
static void hash_keys(size_t idx_start, size_t const& length)
{
    size_t idx_end = idx_start + length;
    for (size_t i = idx_start; i < idx_end; i++)
    {
        Key* k = keys[i];
        // hash key by murmurhash2 or djb2 hash function
        k->hash = external_hash_key(k->data);
    }
}

vector<Key*> keys;

// push all keys into keys vector
external_fill_keys();
size_t num_of_keys = keys.size();

// start threads
vector<thread> workers;

size_t length = num_of_keys / NUM_OF_WORKERS;
size_t remainder = num_of_keys % NUM_OF_WORKERS;

for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_OF_WORKERS; i++)
    workers.push_back(
        thread(
            hash_keys,
            i * length, length
        )
    );

hash_keys(NUM_OF_WORKERS * length, remainder);

// join threads
for (auto& worker : workers)
    worker.join();
```

I have about 3 000 000 keys. If I run the code with single thread - just calling `hash_keys(0, keys.size())` - I get 4.0 seconds estimated time. If I run the code with 4 worker threads I get 5.5 seconds.

The question is why is this slower ? Is reading the same vector from multiple threads not recommended ? And how can I make use of those threads and do this in shorter time?

Comment: Try with `size_t i = idx_start` instead in `hash_keys`. It looks like you are hashing the earlier keys several times.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No sorry. That was a typo. I originally use just `idx_start` as its a copy and I don't need local variable `i`. I edited that.

Comment: What does perf say?

Comment: My guess is that you're thrashing L2 or L3 cache. You could try interleaving the hashing by thread instead of assigning one large chunk (spaced far apart) to each. It's anyone's guess where the `char *` and `Key*` are all created in memory, but they're likely close together.

Comment: Try an optimized solution like tbb::parallel_for

Comment: In what way(s) would `tbb:parallel_for` operate differently than the posted code does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were two problems with my code:

- False sharing, when one thread updated hash of one key, it attempted to write into the same cache line as neighboring thread which slowed down execution significantly
- Each key was created with single `new` call instead of creating more keys at once (not visible in example, this problem occurred in function `external_fill_keys`).

Solution would be creating independent array of keys for each thread and after joining threads, arrays would be concatenated into one large array.